# What is a permission flag?

Tags: android, android-permissions

While defining a new custom permission (using Android Studio), I've noticed that you can assign a "flag" to a permission:

```
android:permissionFlags
```

I looked up [Android Dev docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html), but I could not find any info on this.

Comment: Here is some documentation. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/R.attr.html#permissionFlags